# Simple plot with python igraph

Tags: python-3.x, plot, igraph

I have defined the following simple graph using the python's igraph package:

```
from igraph import *

g = Graph()
g.add_vertices(3)
g.add_edges([(1,0),(0,2),(1,2)])
plot(g)
```

According to the [tutorial on igraph](http://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html#drawing-a-graph-using-a-layout), the `plot(g)` command must

> "... open an external image viewer showing a visual representation of the network ... ".

However, the `plot(g)` command gives an error while I execute the program, that is as follows.

```
Pavithrans-MacBook-Pro:LDPC pavithran$ python simplePlot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "simplePlot.py", line 6, in <module>
    plot(g)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/igraph/drawing/__init__.py", line 458, in plot
    result = Plot(target, bbox, background="white")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/igraph/drawing/__init__.py", line 129, in __init__
    self._surface_was_created = not isinstance(target, cairo.Surface)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/igraph/drawing/utils.py", line 396, in __getattr__
    raise TypeError("plotting not available")
TypeError: plotting not available
```

I am unable to understand where the error is and what exactly I must install in order to account for this error. I have installed Cairo’s Python bindings, XCode and (of course) the igraph package.

I will be very thankful if anyone can suggest me what I must do.

Comment: Can you confirm that Cairo's Python bindings are installed correctly? What does the Python interpreter say when you type `python -c 'import cairo'`? I'm asking this because igraph simply tries to import the `cairo` module in exactly the same way and responds with the `plotting not available` exception if the module cannot be imported.

Comment: see here : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251426/python-igraph-unable-to-plot)