# Python igraph unable to plot

Tags: python, macos, installation, pycairo

I wanted to perform a simple plot with igraph but i get the following error:

```
File "testigraph.py", line 51, in <module>
plot(g, **visual_style)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/igraph/drawing/__init__.py", line 446, in plot
result = Plot(target, bbox, background=kwds.get("background", "white"))
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/igraph/drawing/__init__.py", line 117, in __init__
self._surface_was_created = not isinstance(target, cairo.Surface)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/igraph/drawing/utils.py", line 396, in __getattr__
raise TypeError("plotting not available")
```

It looks like this error [python + igraph "plotting not available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072093/python-igraph-plotting-not-available) but I still cannot fix my problem. I tried following Cairo install instructions on http://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/install.html#installing-igraph but i dont see how to get it working.

--- EDIT

Now I get this error:

```
OSError: dlopen() failed to load a library: cairo / cairo-2
```

I found this solution [Trouble running WeasyPrint after installing El Capitan (OSX 10.11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33530911/trouble-running-weasyprint-after-installing-el-capitan-osx-10-11) but it does not apply to OS X Yosemite. Running

```
csrutil status
```

Returns command not found.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here ! I tried to install pycairo, py2cairo. The installation seemed to be okay but then:

1. I could not import pycairo
2. igraph's plot would not work

---

The following solved the igraph plotting issue:

```
sudo pip install cairocffi
```

So instead of pycairo I used **cairocffi**.